# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'input' was corrupted

Tags: c

I am trying to write a short simple C program where I am trying to store 5 numbers into an array and print them on screen.

Code is as following:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#define size 5

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void){

int i,input[size];

printf("Please enter %d numbers",size);
for (i=0; i<=size-1;++i);{
    scanf("%d",&input[i]);
printf ("Numbers you entered are: \n");
printf("%d",input[i]);}
return 0;
}
```

When I am inputting 1 2 3 4 5 as my 5 numbers to store them in array `input[size]`, I am getting this following error :

`Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'input' was corrupted.`

I know error is something to do with array `input[size]` overflow. But I can't figure out how 1 2 3 4 5 are overflowing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a comment on style: use **(i=0; i < size; ++i)** instead of **(i=0; i <= size-1; ++i)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an incorrect semicolon here:

```
for (i=0; i<=size-1;++i);{       // <---- Incorrect semicolon, braces
    scanf("%d",&input[i]);
printf ("Numbers you entered are: \n");
printf("%d",input[i]);}          // <---- ...closing brace here?
```

Your loop accomplishes nothing. After it completes, `i==5`, and the first value written by `scanf` is at `input[5]` (overrunning the buffer).

Additionally, your brackets make no sense and are not in the correct locations.  If you want to first read 5 numbers, then print your message, then print those 5 numbers, you need to iterate twice.

So it is clear, here is your code, with standard indentation / bracket placement. It should be clear that it doesn't make any sense:

```
int main (void){
    int i, input[size];

    printf("Please enter %d numbers",size);
    for (i=0; i<=size-1; ++i)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    // i=5 now

    // Pointless block
    {
        scanf("%d",&input[i]);               // i=5, overrunning buffer
        printf ("Numbers you entered are: \n");
        printf("%d",input[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's what your code *should* look like (with proper indentation and brackets):

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#define SIZE 5

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i;
    int input[SIZE];

    printf("Please enter %d numbers:\n",SIZE);
    for (i=0; i<=SIZE-1; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &input[i]);
    }

    printf("\nNumbers you entered are: \n");
    for (i=0; i<=SIZE-1; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", input[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Input/Output:**

```
Please enter 5 numbers:
6
5
4
3
2

Numbers you entered are: 
6
5
4
3
2
```

Comment: Good one. Removed semicolon from the following line of code as guided by you @Jonathon Reinhart and got things working. 

    for (i=0; i<=size-1;++i);{           // <-------  

Thanks a lot. I'm sorry but i am still wondering why compiler not throwing it as syntax error.

Comment: Because `;` is a valid statement in C. It means "do nothing", as I've shown in your translated code.